# Uncaught PHP Exception RedisException: "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: php, docker, symfony, redis, docker-compose

Hi I am new to Symfony and am trying to get my Symfony PHP app to connect to my redis cluster.  I keep getting the following error once the images are stood up:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RedisException: "Cannot assign requested address" at /var/www/STATIC/finders/docker/cache/Container4jv3TMx/getSessionService.php line 10 {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): Cannot assign requested address at /var/www/STATIC/finders/docker/cache/Container4jv3TMx/getSessionService.php:10)"} []
```

config.yml

```
imports:
  - { resource: parameters.yml }
  - { resource: ../config.yml }
  - { resource: services.yml }
  - { resource: framework.yml }

monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
      type: stream
      level: debug
      path: 'php://stderr'

twig:
  exception_controller: AppBundle:Exception:showException

framework:
  session:
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    site_host: '%env(SITE_HOST)%'
    #tiler_host: '%site_host%'
    tiler_host: '%env(TILER_HOST)%'
    site_title: '%env(SITE_TITLE)%'
    database_host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
    database_port: '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
    database_name: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
    database_user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
    database_password: '%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%'
    mailer_transport: '%env(MAILER_TRANSPORT)%'
    mailer_host: '%env(MAILER_HOST)%'
    mailer_user: '%env(MAILER_USER)%'
    mailer_password: '%env(MAILER_PASSWORD)%'
    from_email_address: '%env(FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS)%'
    from_email_name: '%env(FROM_EMAIL_NAME)%'
    reply_email_address: '%env(REPLY_EMAIL_ADDRESS)%'
    reply_email_name: '%env(REPLY_EMAIL_NAME)%'
    secret: '%env(SECRET)%'
    root_directory: '%env(ROOT_DIRECTORY)%'
    mapdata_directory: '%env(MAPDATA_DIRECTORY)%'
    version: '%env(VERSION)%'
    theme: '%env(THEME)%'
    geolocation_key: '%env(GEOLOCATION_KEY)%'
    google_maps_key: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY)%'
    google_maps_client: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_CLIENT)%'
    google_maps_channel: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_CHANNEL)%'
    google_maps_crypto_key: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_CRYPTO_KEY)%'
    google_maps_api_version: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_VERSION)%'
    google_maps_initial_zoom_level: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_INITIAL_ZOOM_LEVEL)%'
    google_maps_max_zoom_level: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL)%'
    google_maps_min_zoom_level: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL)%'
    google_maps_initial_lat: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_INITIAL_LAT)%'
    google_maps_initial_lng: '%env(GOOGLE_MAPS_INITIAL_LNG)%'
    google_analytics_site_tag: '%env(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SITE_TAG)%'
    sphinx_host: '%env(SPHINX_HOST)%'
    sphinx_index: '%env(SPHINX_INDEX)%'
    sphinx_host_alt: '%env(SPHINX_HOST_ALT)%'
    sphinx_host_alt2: '%env(SPHINX_HOST_ALT2)%'
    sphinx_host_alt3: '%env(SPHINX_HOST_ALT3)%'
    sphinx_port: '%env(SPHINX_PORT)%'
    search_enable_airports: '%env(SEACH_ENABLE_AIRPORTS)%'
    enable_clustering: '%env(ENABLE_CLUSTERING)%'
    marker_handler: '%env(MARKER_HANDLER)%'
    search_handler: '%env(SEARCH_HANDLER)%'
    search_max_results: '%env(SEARCH_MAX_RESULTS)%'
    search_min_text_search_length: '%env(SEARHC_MIN_TEXT_SEARCH_LEGNTH)%'
    search_ignore_geo_boundary_search: '%env(SEARCH_IGNORE_GEO_BOUNDARY_SEARCH)%'
    search_region_name_restrict: '%env(SEARCH_REGION_NAME_RESTRICT)%'
    search_country_code_restrict: '%env(SEARCH_COUNTRY_CODE_RESTRICT)%'
    search_region_name_restrict_fallback_lat: '%env(SEARCH_REGION_NAME_RESTRICT_FALLBACK_LAT)%'
    search_region_name_restrict_fallback_lng: '%env(SEARCH_REGION_NAME_RESTRICT_FALLBACK_LNG)%'
    locale_default: '%env(LOCALE_DEFAULT)%'
    locale_available: '%env(LOCALE_AVAILABLE)%'
    stackpath_cdn_client_id: '%env(STACKPATH_CDN_CLIENT_ID)%'
    stackpath_cdn_client_secret: '%env(STACKPATH_CDN_CLIENT_SECRET)%'
    iframe_referrers: '%env(IFRAME_REFERRERS)%'
```

framework.yml

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler
```

services.yml

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    Redis:
        class: Redis
        calls:
            - method: connect
              arguments:
                  - '%env(REDIS_HOST)%'
                  - '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
            # If you need key prefix, uncomment line belows
            # - method: setOption
            #   arguments:
            #       - !php/const Redis::OPT_PREFIX
            #       - 'my_prefix'

    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\RedisSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '@Redis'
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM composer:2 AS dependencies

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
RUN mkdir app
COPY ./app/AppKernel.php ./app
COPY ./app/AppCache.php ./app

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

FROM php:7.2-apache

WORKDIR /var/www

# Enable Apache modules
RUN a2enmod cgi \
    expires \
    rewrite

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cgi-mapserver \
    gdal-bin \
    mapserver-bin \
    libdbi-perl \
    libswitch-perl \
    libdbd-mysql-perl \
    libany-uri-escape-perl \
    gdal-bin \
    libcgi-pm-perl \
    #clean up after installs
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Create needed directories
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/cache /var/www/data

# Copy apache virtual host config and startup script
COPY /build/apache/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY /build/start-apache /usr/local/bin
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/start-apache

# Copy source files to the web root folder
COPY ./app /var/www/app
COPY ./bin /var/www/bin
COPY ./src /var/www/src
COPY ./web /var/www/web

#removed access lines from .htaccess

WORKDIR /var/www/web      

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY --from=dependencies /app/vendor /var/www/vendor

RUN chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["start-apache"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web-finder:
    container_name: web-finder
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - web-finder

  session_cache:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - web-finder

networks:
  web-finder:
```

I am using docker-compose up to spin all of this up.  The error happens as I hit localhost:8080.  I get the same error locally as I do in the AWS Environment with an elasticache cluster.

Comment: Which value do you have in the `REDIS_HOST ` env variable ?

Comment: @Reqven I have 
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PORT=6379

Comment: Use your redis service name `session_cache` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by changing the value of `REDIS_HOST` in the environment variable.

changed from `REDIS_HOST = localhost` to `REDIS_HOST=redis`

Comment: note, that you have to use the same host in your nc `config.php` file. e.g. if you use `docker-compose` and call the container `redis`, the host is also just "redis" in both, the environmentvariable and in the php config file